# Matching a pattern in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string

```
string str = "I am fine. How are you? You need exactly 4 pieces of sandwiches. Your ADAST Count  is  5. Okay thank you ";
```

What I want is, get the ADAST count value. For the above example, it is `5`.

The problem here is, the `is` after the `ADAST Count`. It can be `is` or `=`. But there will the two words `ADAST Count`.

What I have tried is

```
var resultString = Regex.Match(str, @"ADAST\s+count\s+is\s+\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
var number = Regex.Match(resultString, @"\d+").Value;
```

How can I write the pattern which will search `is` or `=` ?

Comment: try `[is|=]` instead of just `is`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ADAST\s+count\s+(?:is|=)\s+(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=ADAST%5Cs%2Bcount%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Ais%7C%3D%29%5Cs%2B%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=I%20am%20fine.%20How%20are%20you%3F%20You%20need%20exactly%204%20pieces%20of%20sandwiches.%20Your%20ADAST%20Count%20%20is%20%205.%20Okay%20thank%20you%20&o=im)

Note that `(?:is|=)` is a [*non-capturing group*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) (i.e. it is used to only group alternations without pushing these submatches on to the capture stack for further retrieval) and `|` is an [*alternation* operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

**Details**:

- `ADAST` - a literal string
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `count` - a literal string
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces

  - `(?:is|=)` - either `is` or `=`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more digits

C#:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"ADAST\s+count\s+(?:is|=)\s+(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success) {
    Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thank for the explanation :). Another thing, what it mean by `Group 1` in `(\d+)` ?